# How to replace "key": value pairs in string with key: value (remove quotes from key)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I need to remove quotes in string **from keys**. Here is a code:

```
import re
mystr = '["key": val, "key2": val, "key3": v, "key5": 34, "key6": "ef"]'

key_pattern = "(\"(?P<key>\w+)\": )"
pattern = re.compile(key_pattern)
print(re.sub(pattern, "\key", mystr))
```

This is not working.
I need to get the result:

```
mystr = '[key: val, key2: val, key3: v, key5: 34, key6: "ef"]'
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo `.replace('"', '')` does not solve the current problem, see the `"ef"` that should stay as is. Please retract the close vote.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew indeed. Good call, thanks for the correction

Comment: Did you have time to check your code? If you need more help please show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
"(\w+)"(?=:)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lyzytb/1). Details:

- `"` - a `"` char
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more letters, digits, `_`
- `"` - a `"` char
- `(?=:)` - the next char must be `:`

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/bxyn7B):

```
import re
mystr = '["key": val, "key2": val, "key3": v, "key5": 34, "key6": "ef"]'
key_pattern = '"(\w+)"(?=:)'
print(re.sub(key_pattern, r"\1", mystr))
# => [key: val, key2: val, key3: v, key5: 34, key6: "ef"]
```

Comment: thanks, it works in python3.8, but I have python3.5 and r"\1" not working with python3.5 if I know..

Comment: @KateZz `r"\1"` works even in Python 2.x. Please share a fiddle (code demo using any online IDE Web site) if you coma across any issues with the solution.

Comment: @KateZz you can try `r"\g<1>"` instead

Comment: @KateZz You must have some typo in your code, please try my code exactly as in the demo, or share the code for me to check.